# MySQL Cursors - having errors in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql program, which has cursors in it. Due to an error in writing an DECLARE query, MySQL Workbench is always showing me the DECLARE is not valid at this position, expected EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN, BINLOG, CACHE, ...

Could you help me solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //

BEGIN

declare Naslov_knjige VARCHAR(24);
declare Cena_knjige   DECIMAL(8,2);

DECLARE cursor_cene CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        Naslov, 
        Cena
    FROM 
        prvi_test_v2.knjige;

OPEN cursor_cene //

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_cene INTO 
    @Naslov_knjige, 
    @Cena_knjige //

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @Naslov_knjige + CAST(@Cena_knjige AS VARCHAR) //
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_cene INTO 
            @Naslov_knjige, 
            @Cena_knjige //
    END //

CLOSE cursor_cene //

DEALLOCATE cursor_cene //

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you omitted a line for CREATE PROCEDURE, because in MySQL a BEGIN...END block must be part of a stored routine. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html

> BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events).

You changed the DELIMITER:

```
DELIMITER //
```

Using this delimiter terminates the whole CREATE PROCEDURE statement. You should not do this after the first statement in the body of the procedure. You need to use the normal `;` terminators for each statement within the body of the procedure. The reason for changing the delimiter is so you can use `;` for each statement in the procedure without ending the CREATE PROCEDURE.

See examples and documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

That's the reason for the error you got. You used `//` to terminate `OPEN cursor_cene //` which ended the CREATE PROCEDURE, but clearly there was more to that procedure.

There are other problems with your procedure. You seem to be using Microsoft SQL Server syntax, but MySQL is different.

`Naslov_knjige` is not the same variable as `@Naslov_knjige` in MySQL. Don't use the `@` sigil in front of local variables. If you use the `@` sigil, this refers to a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

The `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` syntax is specific to Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL has different syntax for running a cursor loop. See example in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

That's as far as I got. There may be more problems, but I am not going to look for them.